# Optimal coefficient in Cauchy-Schwartz inequality?

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This may be trivially wrong, but I can't see a counterargument. Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be measurable complex-valued functions such that $f/g$ is defined. Does there exist a coefficient $\alpha(f/g)$ depending only on their quotient as a measurable function such that
$$
|(f,g)|\le\alpha(f/g)\|f\|\|g\|.
$$
$\alpha(h)=1$ if $h=\mathrm{const}$ (different from 0), so maybe $\alpha$, if it exists, has to do with the variance. Thank you.

Comment: What is $0/0$ for you?

Comment: My guess is: Unless $h$ is the zero function we will get $\alpha(h)=1$. Namely, both $f, g$ and $C 1_{A} f + 1_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A} f, C 1_{A} g + 1_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A} g$ give the same $h$ for all constants $C$ and every measurable set $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I still don't see why
$$
\sup_{C,A}\frac{|(C\mathrm{1}_Af+\mathrm{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}f,C\mathrm{1}_Ag+\mathrm{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}g)|}{\|C\mathrm{1}_Af+\mathrm{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}f\|\|C\mathrm{1}_Ag+\mathrm{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}g\|}=1.
$$

Comment: My intuition is that we can pick $A$ almost a level set of $h$ and $C$ so big that the rest is small in comparison. Then the modified functions are almost scalar multiples of each other. Nothing I wrote it rigorous, otherwise I would have posted an answer.

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $C$ and let it go to infinity. Then you get that a lower bound of your quantity $$ \sup_A \frac{(1_A f, 1_A g)}{\Vert 1_A f\Vert \cdot \Vert 1_A g\Vert} $$ However, if you pick $A$ to be roughly a level set of $h$ (not of zero of course and not having zero measure either) then $f $ is roughly $\lambda g$ and the quotient should go to 1. Still not rigorous, however, something that one can possibly work with.

Comment: To simplify, we can choose $g=1$ and $f=h$. Then a lower bound for $\alpha(h)$ is $$\sup_A \frac{(1_A h, 1_A)}{\Vert 1_A h\Vert \cdot \Vert 1_A\Vert}.$$

Comment: If $h$ is not the zero function, then there exists $\xi\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ the set $A_\varepsilon :=h^{-1}([\xi-\varepsilon, \xi +\varepsilon])$ has positive measure. If needed we can intersect with some bounded set to render the measure of $A_\varepsilon$ finite. Then we have for $\varepsilon$ small enough $$(1_{A_\varepsilon} h, 1_{A_\varepsilon})\geq  (\xi -\varepsilon) \Vert 1_{A_\varepsilon} \Vert^2$$

Comment: On the other hand we have $$\Vert 1_{A_\varepsilon} h \Vert \leq (\xi +\varepsilon) \Vert 1_{A_\varepsilon} \Vert$$ Hence a lower bound is $\frac{\xi-\varepsilon}{\xi+\varepsilon}$. But if we make $\varepsilon$ small, then this goes to $1$. I'll make those things into an answer when I have slept (if they still make sense).

Comment: Funny, you claim to be so rigorous, still you seem not to care about the mistakes in your question. Eg that you cannot start from general measurable function as the quotient will not be defined or that $\alpha(h)=1$ iff $h$ constant (where you could at least remove $h=0$). You should try to live up to your own standards at least a bit...

Answer (score 1):

If $h$ is not equal to zero almost everywhere, then $\alpha(h)=1$.

First let us restrict ourselves to $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Otherwise we run into troubles with multiplying zero and infinity. I am assuming that we are talking about the Lebesgue measure with the usual Lebesgue sigma-algebra.

**Case 1: h equal to zero almost everywhere.**
Let's take care of the trivial case. If $h$ is almost everywhere equal to zero, then we have $f=h$ a.e. and $g$ some a.e. positive $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ function. Then we have
$$ \vert (f, g) \vert = 0  $$
As also $\Vert f \Vert=0$, we can pick $\alpha(h)$ whatever we like (even negative constants).

**Case 2: if h is not equal to zero almost everywhere.** 
Let $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $h$ is not almost everywhere equal to zero. First we note that there always exist admissible $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions such that $h=f/g$, for example if $H\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ positive, then
$$ f= \left(\frac{1_{\{\vert h \vert \geq 1\}}}{h} + 1_{\{\vert h\vert <1\}} h \right) H, \qquad
g= \left(\frac{1_{\{\vert h \vert \geq 1\}}}{h^2} + 1_{\{\vert h\vert <1\}} \right) H  $$ 
do the job. We have
$$ \alpha(h) = \sup_{f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): h=f/g} \frac{\vert (f,g) \vert}{\Vert f \Vert \cdot \Vert g\Vert}.$$
Note that $\Vert f \Vert, \Vert g \Vert \neq 0$ as $h$ is not equal zero almost everywhere. Furthermore, by Cauchy-Schwarz we know that $\alpha(h) \leq 1$. *Hence, we just need to show that $\alpha(h)\geq 1$.*

**Handwaving outline:** Our strategy is the following. We can replace $f,g$ by $1_A f, 1_A g$. Then we will pick $A$ to be roughly a level set of $h$. In that case we have that $1_Af, 1_A g$ are almost scalar multiples of each other. Then we get that the quotient is roughly one.

**Actual proof:** In general we have for $C>0$ and $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ measurable set not being a null set, that if $f,g$ are admissible, then so are $1_A f + \frac{1}{C} 1_{A^c} f $, $1_A g + \frac{1}{C} 1_{A^c} g $.

Hence, if we let $C$ go to infinity, we get for every $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ measurable set such that $\{ h \neq 0 \}\cap A$ is not a null set (and thus $\Vert 1_A f \Vert, \Vert 1_A g\Vert \neq 0$)
$$ \alpha(h) \geq \sup_{f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): h=f/g} \frac{\vert (1_A f,1_A g) \vert}{\Vert 1_A f \Vert \cdot \Vert 1_A g\Vert}. $$
Now we want to make $A$ almost a level set of $h$ such that $1_A f$ and $1_A g$ are almost scalar multiples of each other.

First we note that $\alpha(h) = \alpha(-h)$, hence, we wlog of generality we may assume that $\{ h>0\}$ is not a null set. Thus, we can pick $R>0$ such that $\{h>0 \}\cap [-R,R]$ is not a null set. For every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\xi(\varepsilon)>0$ such that 
$$A_\varepsilon := \{h>0 \} \cap h^{-1}([\xi(\varepsilon) -\varepsilon, \xi(\varepsilon) + \varepsilon]) \cap [-R, R]$$
is not a null set. By subdividing the interval $[\xi(\varepsilon) -\varepsilon, \xi(\varepsilon) + \varepsilon]$ we find a sequence $(\xi_{n_l})_{l \geq 1}$ ($n_l < n_{l+1}$) such that $\xi_{n_l}\geq 1/\sqrt{n_l}$ and such that
$$ B_{n_l} :=  h^{-1}([\xi_{n_l} -1/n_l, \xi_{n_l} + 1/n_l]) \cap [-R, R] $$
is not a null set. Now, if we pick $A=B_{n_l}$ and $f=h$, $g=1$ on $B_{n_1}$ (this we are allowed to do as $B_{n_1}$ has finite measure as it is a subset of $[-R,R]$ and $h$ is bounded on that set) we get
$$ \alpha(h) \geq \frac{\vert (1_{B_{n_l}} h,1_{B_{n_l}} 1) \vert}{\Vert 1_{B_{n_l}} h \Vert \cdot \Vert 1_{B_{n_l}} g\Vert} 
\geq \frac{(\xi_{n_l} - 1/n_l) \Vert 1_{B_{n_l}} \Vert^2}{(\xi_{n_l} + 1/n_l) \Vert 1_{B_{n_l}} \Vert^2} 
= \frac{(\xi_{n_l} - 1/n_l)}{(\xi_{n_l} + 1/n_l)}
\geq \frac{(\xi_{n_l} - 1/n_l)}{\xi_{n_l}} 
\geq \frac{(1-1/\sqrt{n_l}) \xi_{n_l}}{\xi_{n_l}}= (1-1/\sqrt{n_l}).$$
Let $l$ go to infinity, then we obtain
$$ \alpha(h) \geq 1.$$

**Added:** It was pointed out in the comments that it is not obvious that we can choose $\xi_{n_l}\geq 1/\sqrt{n_l}$. Let me elaborate on that. We know that there exists some $L>0$ such that
$$ A := \{h>0 \} \cap h^{-1}((0,L]) \cap [-R, R] $$ 
has positive measure. Writing
$$ A = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} \left( \{h>0 \} \cap h^{-1}((L/2^{n},L/2^{n-1}]) \cap [-R, R] \right) $$
we get that there exists $\xi >0$ such that
$$ \{h>0 \} \cap h^{-1}([\xi,L]) \cap [-R, R]  $$
has positive measure. Now pick $n_1$ such that $\xi \geq 1/\sqrt{n_1}$. We have for $N\geq n_1$
$$ \{h>0 \} \cap h^{-1}([\xi,L]) \cap [-R, R]
= \bigcup_{j=0}^{N^2-1}h^{-1}([\xi + j\frac{L-\xi}{N^2}, \xi + (j+1) \frac{L-\xi}{N^2} ])\cap [-R, R] $$
Then one of those sets will have positive measure and the length of the interval is $\frac{L-\xi}{N^2}$ and the midpoints of the intervals are greater or equal to $\xi$. Hence, we in particularly pick $\xi_n$ in the way I wrote above (in fact I can make the length of the intervals to decay as fast as I want and the inequality of the midpoints versus the length could be taken as good as you would like).

Comment: Thank you for your substantial work. I don't think that the set $B_1$ has been defined, and to me it is not obvious that you can choose $\xi_{n_l}>\frac1{\sqrt{n_l}}$. Would you, please, elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: The first was a typo, I meant $B_{n_1}$.

Comment: For the second, I will elaborate a bit when I habe time. It is annoying to type it on my phone.

Comment: But except from those minor things, is it fine? Or are there other things that are not clear?

Comment: The idea is clear. Whether or not everything works I will be able to tell after you fill in the gap. And then there might arise other gaps. I am like a compiler in that respect :)

Comment: I spelled out the boring details. It really is nothing else than dividing the interval into subintervals as claimed.

Comment: All right, it sort of works. Thank you. You would change $q$ to $n$ in the 10th displayed formula. Also, do not forget $\{h>0\}$ in the definition $B_{n_l}$, just for consistency. The arbitrariness of $\epsilon>0$ is unnecessary, you could have taken $\epsilon=1$ to avoid confusion. Finally, $\xi_{n_l}>\frac1{\sqrt{n_l}}$ is weaker than $\xi_{n_l}>\frac1{\sqrt{n_1}}$, and the latter is less confusing. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no need for $\{ h >0\}$ and I strongly disagree, I like more general statement coming for free, like that it is true for any $\varepsilon >0$. I prefer the weaker inequality as it reflects how I think about it, we don't need the stronger estimate. Also for me none of the above is really confusing... I gave first the idea and then all the details. I really don't like that you write "it sort of works". If you have something that is not clear, then just say so.